# Need a starting point for using the Yodlee Wizards

Tags: wizard, yodlee

I'm just getting started using Yodlee, and I'm excited about the prospect of using the Linked Account Wizard (among the others.)  Unfortunately, the only documentation I've found so far on them is a brief mention of "Yodlee Hosted Wizards" in the SDK Developer's Guide.  Is there more documentation on them anywhere in the Yodlee documentation trove?  It's tricky to know where to start with these things.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check out the doc Aggregation Quick Reference Guide-11.1.pdf from this page:

http://developers.yodlee.com/docs-tools-how-tos

Comment: Unfortunately, this link is a now a 404... it appears as though yodlee have moved the content, and a search doesn't reveal an obvious answer so this is a bit of a dead end I was hoping to find the docs on this myself.

Comment: It might be they intended the documents to only be accessible if you are logged in. Unfortunate but not uncommon with paid APIs.

Answer (score 1):

Nick is right there's a bit more instruction on LAW in the aggregation quickstart guide. That's available in our dev portal and v11 ftp server. There are some additional docs on the ftp server not currently on our dev portal. If you don't have access to that send a request here  http://solutions.yodlee.com/web-inquiry.html and David will get you hooked up.